# How to fix random NPE and "Neo.ClientError.Statement.EntityNotFound" when doing multiple Neo4j CRUD operations in parallel?

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, junit4, spring-data-neo4j-4

I am using Spring data neo4j - 4 and to verify the behaviour of my service layer, i ran multiple Junit tests that perform domain (CRUD) operations on various neo4j Nodes and also create and delete relationships. These operations and tests are not dependent on each other. Sporadically I get this error for different tests.

```
org.neo4j.ogm.session.result.ResultProcessingException: "errors"[{"code":"Neo.ClientError.Statement.EntityNotFound","message":"Node with id 24213"}]}
[error]     at      org.neo4j.ogm.session.response.JsonResponse.parseErrors(JsonResponse.java:165)
[error]     at org.neo4j.ogm.session.response.JsonResponse.next(JsonResponse.java:101)
[error]     at org.neo4j.ogm.session.response.JsonResponse.next(JsonResponse.java:30)
[error]     at org.neo4j.ogm.session.response.GraphRowModelResponse.next(GraphRowModelResponse.java:52)
[error]     at org.neo4j.ogm.session.response.GraphRowModelResponse.next(GraphRowModelResponse.java:32)
[error]     at org.neo4j.ogm.session.response.SessionResponseHandler.loadByProperty(SessionResponseHandler.java:55)
[error]     at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.LoadByTypeDelegate.loadAll(LoadByTypeDelegate.java:81)
[error]     at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.LoadByTypeDelegate.loadAll(LoadByTypeDelegate.java:109)
[error]     at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.loadAll(Neo4jSession.java:158
```

The interesting thing is that this is happening for random test scenarios. I have made sure that I use different new sessions for different tests and also for the set up. The service classes create their own session. But none of this seems to be helping.

Is this a problem with the driver or the spring layer or with neo4j itself? Any suggestions, what possibly could help to fix the issue?

The NPE:

```
    <failure message="Error mapping GraphModel to instance of com.mylivn.neo4j.domain.User"         type="org.neo4j.ogm.metadata.MappingException">org.neo4j.ogm.metadata.MappingException: Error mapping GraphModel to instance of com.mylivn.neo4j.domain.User
at          org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.GraphEntityMapper.mapEntities(GraphEntityMapper.java:97)
at org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.GraphEntityMapper.map(GraphEntityMapper.java:69)
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.response.SessionResponseHandler.loadByProperty(SessionResponseHandler.java:60)
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.LoadByTypeDelegate.loadAll(LoadByTypeDelegate.java:81)
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.LoadByTypeDelegate.loadAll(LoadByTypeDelegate.java:109)
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.loadAll(Neo4jSession.java:158)
at com.mylivn.neo4j.services.utils.Neo4jHelper.getByUuid(Neo4jHelper.scala:39
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.neo4j.ogm.entityaccess.DefaultEntityAccessStrategy.getPropertyWriter(DefaultEntityAccessStrategy.java:77)
at org.neo4j.ogm.entityaccess.DefaultEntityAccessStrategy.getPropertyWriter(DefaultEntityAccessStrategy.java:47)
at org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.GraphEntityMapper.writeProperty(GraphEntityMapper.java:145)
at org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.GraphEntityMapper.setProperties(GraphEntityMapper.java:138)
at org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.GraphEntityMapper.createRelationshipEntity(GraphEntityMapper.java:272)
at org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.GraphEntityMapper.mapRelationshipEntity(GraphEntityMapper.java:233)
at org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.GraphEntityMapper.mapRelationships(GraphEntityMapper.java:197)
at org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.GraphEntityMapper.mapEntities(GraphEntityMapper.java:95)
... 79 more
```

whats more puzzling the NPE failure . As i look at the code, if the request is coming in a thread, unless another thread removes the entry from propertyWriterCache, it should not fail.
this seems to be not thread safe, but I do not see any code to delete entries from propertyWriterCache

Code from where NPE is thrown

```
@Override
public EntityAccess getPropertyWriter(final ClassInfo classInfo, String propertyName) {
if(!propertyWriterCache.containsKey(classInfo))
{ propertyWriterCache.put(classInfo,new HashMap<String, EntityAccess>()); }
if(propertyWriterCache.get(classInfo).containsKey(propertyName))
{ //*line77* return propertyWriterCache.get(classInfo).get(propertyName); }
MethodInfo setterInfo = classInfo.propertySetter(propertyName);
EntityAccess propertyWriter = determinePropertyAccessor(classInfo, propertyName, setterInfo, new AccessorFactory<EntityAccess>() {
@Override
public EntityAccess makeMethodAccessor(MethodInfo methodInfo)
{ return new MethodWriter(classInfo, methodInfo); }
@Override
public EntityAccess makeFieldAccessor(FieldInfo fieldInfo)
{ return new FieldWriter(classInfo, fieldInfo); }
});
propertyWriterCache.get(classInfo).put(propertyName, propertyWriter);
return propertyWriter;
}
```

Comment: The error is coming from Neo4j itself, but without knowing how your various sessions and threads are inter-operating its pretty hard to determine an underlying cause. If one transaction creates a node, and another transaction tries to read it before the first transaction commits, you would get this error. So if your read/write transactions are running on different threads but sharing state you could easily get out-of-order operations occurring.  That's where I'd look first.

Comment: I use org.springframework.data.neo4j.template.Neo4jOperations#save to save/create the entity. As I recall from the documentation page http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#_transactions, the template save method provides auto-commit transactions. Do I need to specifically create one transaction and commit after save call has returned?

Comment: No you don't need to explicitly create a transaction - the save will auto-commit as you say. Are you making calls to Neo4jTemplate on different threads?

Comment: no, for a given test, I create a set of entities using session/s and then run my service in another session. this all in a single thread. Many such setups--->test sequences run in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

I met with the same problem while frequently saving one NodeEntity by using Session.save().The underlying cause I think is that when invoking Session.save(),
NodeEntity's related modified object (involves Relationship,RelationshipEntity and path)  will save again.So when having scene that having multi case run in parallel,it would lead to data asynchronous.

Finally,I replaced saving the modified NodeEntity with saving RelationshipEntity .This temporarily solve the problem.Hope to help you.

**Note:** This isn't a best solution.